# Who was the guy who tipped off They Walk Among Us in the first book?

Tags: lorien-legacies, i-am-number-four

Remember the guy who told They Walk Among Us about Mogadorians in *I Am Number Four*? Who was he? We're now on the penultimate book and the author seems to have forgotten him already. I really wanted to know who is he. Or was this answered in some of the Lost Files already? I haven't read some of it, so I don't know.

Hopefully some of you Lorics out there will enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

At this point after all six main book and 13 lost file have been published, especially after *"The Guard"* , we can assumed this person is Lexa - one of three adult Loric escape Lorien on second ship with Ella

> *... he discovers print copies of a now-defunct newsletter called They
>   Walk Among Us, a publication I’d been feeding information and funds to
>   for years ...*
> - The Guard, Chapter 8

But again, it a bit not so sure about this because

> *Planet Lorien? The Loric?
> 1–3dead
> 4?
> 7 trailed in Spain.
>  9 on the run in SA*
> - I Am Number Four, Chapter 21

Yes she know about first two line, maybe the third too but how she know location(s) of Number 7 and Number 9, since she can't hack to the Mog system (she mention it few time not want to be expose without knowing it) and she don't have the table which can locate the Garde. Or this just another conflict because the author not really done any research of the pre book(s) - another one is when Sarah say Crayton killed in Spain (at Chapter 10) while actually he killed later in India